# Could not load type from assembly 'App_Code'

Tags: c#, asp.net, http

I want to create a custom HTTP module in asp.net. [This article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms227673(v=vs.85).aspx) shows how to do it I followed the steps and here is my class which inherits from `IHttpModule`

```
public class LanguageModule : IHttpModule
{

    public void Init(HttpApplication context)
    {
        context.AcquireRequestState += new EventHandler(OnAcquireRequestState);
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {

    }

    public void OnAcquireRequestState(Object i_object, EventArgs i_eventArgs)
    {
        HttpApplication l_httpApplication = i_object as HttpApplication;

        // check whether the language change parameter has been passed
        var l_language =
            l_httpApplication.Request.Params[Constants.SESSION_LANGUAGE];
        var l_boolLanguageChanged = false;
        if (l_language == null)
        {
            // if language parameter is not sent, then take language from session
            l_language = (string)l_httpApplication.Session[Constants.SESSION_LANGUAGE];
        }
        else
        {
            // If language parameter is indeed sent, then user wants to change language.
            // I will make sure I tag this in order to redirect to.
            l_boolLanguageChanged = true;
        }

        // having the language a thand, let us set it.
        var l_culture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo(l_language);

        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = l_culture;
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = l_culture;

        // save language to session
        l_httpApplication.Session[Constants.SESSION_LANGUAGE] = l_language;

        // check whether I have redirect
        if (l_boolLanguageChanged && l_httpApplication.Request.UrlReferrer != null)
        {
            l_httpApplication.Response.Redirect(
               l_httpApplication.Request.UrlReferrer.AbsolutePath);
        }

    } // OnAcquireRequestState
    //-------------------------

} // class LanguageModule
```

Then I registered this module in `web.config` file like so

```
<httpModules>
       <add name="LanguageSettingModule" type="LanguageModule, App_Code" />
</httpModules>
```

I tried also to register it under `system.web` tag like so

```
<system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
        <add name="LanguageSettingModule" type="LanguageModule, App_Code" />
    </modules>
</system.webServer>
```

file `LanguageModule` is placed under App_Code folder

But I'm always getting this error

> Could not load type from assembly 'App_Code'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `App_Code` from your configuration setting. In your `web.config` it should look like below. Even the MSDN document you linked, shows the same way of registering.

```
<httpModules>
       <add name="LanguageSettingModule" type="LanguageModule" />
</httpModules>
```

Comment: Thank you sir for your answer, this is solved the problem. Now Index page has loaded successfully.To test it I made a breakpoint at Init function within LanguageModule but it won't fire. Do you know why this happens

Comment: If you mouse over the breakpoint; what does it say? Also, consider posting it as separate question. You may link this question for reference.